# Convert C# Byte Array to Object Threw SerializationException

Tags: c#, soap, xamarin, dataset, arrays

I am developing an iOS project using Xamarin that uses C# for both .NET (SOAP) Web Service and iOS. I am trying to send DataSet object from the web service to mobile in the form of byte array. I used the [following](http://www.morgantechspace.com/2013/08/convert-object-to-byte-array-and-vice.html) code to convert to/from byte array:

```
public static byte[] ConvertObjectToByteArray(Object obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
        return null;
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    if (obj.GetType() == typeof(DataSet))
    {
        DataSet ds = (DataSet)obj;
        ds.RemotingFormat = SerializationFormat.Binary;
    }
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}

public static Object ConvertByteArrayToObject(byte[] byteArr)
{
    Object resultObj;
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArr))
    {
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        resultObj = (Object) bf.Deserialize(ms);
        ms.Close();
    }
    return resultObj;
}
```

However when I try to convert the byte array back to DataSet sent from WebService to mobile, I got an exception 'Unexpected binary element: 101' from the 'Deserialize' method. I tried the following but still couldn't figure out:

1. Convert DataSet to byte[] and convert back to DataSet in WebService, it works correctly
2. Convert DataSet to byte[] and convert back to DataSet in mobile, it works correctly
3. I debugged and checked that the byte array length and first few bytes are the same when about to be sent from WebService and when received at mobile.

Anyone has any clue or any experience with sending byte[] over SOAP Web Service?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That could happen because the two might handle (de)serialization slightly differently. or simply because one of the two has a bug (assuming Mono here). Anyway, try going with non-binary serialization for beginning to see what happens. You can still convert XML text to binary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find workaround for this using another serialization function as follows:

```
private byte[] Compress(DataSet dataset)
{
    Byte[] data;
    MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream();
    GZipStream zip = new GZipStream(mem, CompressionMode.Compress);
    dataset.WriteXml(zip, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
    zip.Close();
    data = mem.ToArray();
    mem.Close();
    return data;
}

private DataSet Decompress(Byte[] data)
{
    MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream(data);
    GZipStream zip = new GZipStream(mem, CompressionMode.Decompress);
    DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
    dataset.ReadXml(zip, XmlReadMode.ReadSchema);
    zip.Close();
    mem.Close();
    return dataset;
}
```

Credit to this [post](http://tittylouis.blogspot.be/2011/02/compressing-and-decompressing-dataset.html)